# Fill a combobox retrieving data from two different columns

Tags: vb.net, datatable, combobox

I have a datatable (`treno1`) containing 10 columns about group railway reservation. I need to know how many people loaded into a single car and how many people go to a single city.

I get a json reservation from a web.

```
With treno1
    .Columns.Add("Partenza", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Arrivo", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("PNR", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Classe", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Cognome", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Carrozza", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Posto", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Nome", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Treno", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("ID prenotazione", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
End With


For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()

    For Each msg As JObject In item.Values
        treno1.Rows.Add(msg("departureLocationName"), msg("arrivalLocationName"), msg("pnrCode"), msg("serviceLevel"), msg("lastName"), msg("wagon"), msg("seat"), msg("firstName"), msg("transportMeanName"), msg("Id"))
    Next
Next
```

I don't understand how to fill `combobox1` with values from `partenza` and `arrivo`. These are columns with the departure station and arrival station.

I want `combobox1` to be filled with all unique stations. An sql solution would be the best way but I can't understand how to make this query.
column0 has roma,firenze,bologna;column1 has firenze,bologna,milano
**i want combobox1 with roma,firenze,bologna,milano (without duplicates)**

I even tried

```
Private conn As New OleDbConnection 
Dim dbprovider = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" 
Dim dbsource As String
Dim sql As String 
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter 
dbsource = "treno1" 
conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource conn.Open() sql = "SELECT Partenza FROM tabella1 UNION SELECT Arrivo FROM tabella1 " 
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn) 
ComboBox1.DataSource = da
```

Comment: Since, for some reason, you're adding Rows one by one, you could declare a new `List(Of String)` before the loop, in the loop add the `departureLocationName` and `arrivalLocationName` values to the list; after the loop, `comboBox1.DataSource = [Your List].OrderBy(function(s) s).Distinct().ToArray()`. This, if you just need the stations names and nothing else.

Comment: To be more explicit, the previous comment is meant to trigger a response from you, since it's not clear what you want to show in your ComboBox: e.g., a combination of `"departure - arrival"` as a single string, `{ "departure", "arrival", "departure", ... }` as an array of distinct strings, an object containing single, distinct, ordered stations which is also connected to the source DataRow (bound) or something else.

Comment: `select Partenza jointColumn from Table1 union all select Arrivo from Table1`

Comment: Don't do this: `.Columns.Add("Partenza", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))`. Do this instead: `.Columns.Add("Partenza", GetType(String))`. Only use a `String` to specify the data type if it is coming from some other source. If you're hard-coding it, use an actual data type that the compiler can confirm is valid.

Comment: i have a column with firenze,bologna,milano and another one with roma,firenze,bologna several times .my final point is to have combobox1 with roma,firenze,bologna,milano.that's it

Comment: due it's a datatable filled from a json,how i could open a sql connection ???

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: You have a possible solution in my first comment. Didn't you try that?

Comment: it gives me an error in the function.

Comment: i don't understand how to make it with sql statement

Comment: *it gives me an error* is not really descriptive, isn't it? Did you declare a `List(Of String)` (outside the loop)? That code requires a reference to `System.Linq`, which is usually already included in new Projects, you just need to add `Imports System.Linq` on top of your class/module. Btw, you need to prefix a nickname with `@` to ping someone (as in `@fabio`)

Comment: @T.S. which connection would you set ? i tried this code but says "Invalid string initialization" Private conn As New OleDbConnection
 Dim dbprovider = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
 Dim dbsource As StringDim sql As String
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    dbsource = "treno1"
    conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
    conn.Open()
    sql = "SELECT Partenza FROM tabella1
   UNION
   SELECT Arrivo FROM tabella1 "
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = da

Comment: @fabio Any additional code should be added to the question. The error is about design-time. your code syntax is wrong

Comment: @T.S. i'm becoming mad : how could connect to a datable,to make sql query....

Comment: I doubt `ComboBox1.DataSource = da` -- doubt that data adapter can be a data source. Data source is DataTable or List(), or array

Comment: @T.S. probably it's not possibile to do this what i'm looking for.i looked around but i found only examples with external db.thanks anyway !!

Comment: nothing is impossible.

Comment: A datatable could be inquired with sql???